# Two columns of three DIV's each

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two columns of three vertical DIV's side by side. The left column is the main text area and the right column is for misc info.
The top and bottom DIV of each column is just an image with rounded corners. The center DIV is for the text. Furthermore, I would ideally like the center DIV in each column fo automatically expand vertically in proportion with the text content.

Following is my CSS:

```
.main_bkgd_tp_img {
    background: url(../images/text.main.tp.gif);
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
 }
 .main_bkgd_btm_img {
    background: url(../images/text.main.btm.gif);
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
 }
 .mainbody {
    background: url(../images/text.main.fill.gif);
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
 }
 .mainbody .text {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    width:95%;
 }
 .mainbody p {
    position:relative;
    font:normal 12px verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    line-height:15px;
 }
 .mainbody h1, h2 {
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
    line-height:15px;
  }
 .rtcol_bkgd_tp_img {
    background: url(../images/rtcol.main.tp.gif);
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .rtcol_bkgd_btm_img {
    background: url(../images/rtcol.main.btm.gif);
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
 }
 .rtcolbody {
    background: url(../images/rtcol.main.fill.gif);
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
 }
 .rtcolbody .text {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:20px;
    width:95%;
 }
 .rtcolbody p {
    position:relative;
    font:normal 12px verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    line-height:15px;
 }
 .rtcolbody h1, h2 {
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
    line-height:15px;
 }
```

And following is my HTML:

```
 <div class="main_bkgd_tp_img"></div>
 <div class="mainbody">
      <div class="text">
          <h4> This is made up text just for testing purposes. The real text will be added later.</h4>
          <h4> This is more made up text just for testing purposes. The real text will be added later. </h4>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_bkgd_btm_img"></div>
  <div class="rtcol_bkgd_tp_img"></div>
  <div class="rtcolbody">
      <div class="text">
          <h4> This is a test. </h4> <br/>
          <h4>This text is just for testing purposes. The real text will be added later. </h4>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="rtcol_bkgd_btm_img"></div>
```

The actual page in process can be seen [here](http://www.rkmpcservices.com/azdance/company.html).

Thank you!

---

I believe I figured this out.
For each of the "rtcol_...." CSS entries I changed "float:right" to "margin-left: 420px.

I still need to know how to make the middle DIV expand automatically in correlation with the text content.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  For future reference, indenting the code with four spaces will Pretty-Print it.

Comment: What browsers are you trying to support?  You can create the rounded corners with just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would build the page layout in a bit different way wrapping each column in its own div, but anyway. Modify you css like this:

- in `.rtcolbody` and `.mainbody` set `height: auto;` or simply remove that line
- in `.rtcolbody .text` and `.mainbody .text` remove `position: absoulute;`

Comment: Never mind. With your suggested means of coding, the image floats perfectly using the standard float object. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If i go with your style code so you should make some changes in your CSS as i am mentioning below:-

remove the the **positioning** from class.**text** and give min-height to class **mainbody**....

```
.mainbody {
    background: url("../images/text.main.fill.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    min-height: 300px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
}        

.mainbody .text {
        padding: 20px 12px;

    }
```

And there one another CSS3 method of your question you can give **curve** and **background transparent** into your box see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/31/

And through this method you can increase and decrease the opacity of background and that will not affect the text color inside your box its simple see the css basically you have to use the rgb color in background alpa for opacity & you don't need use images and extra div's for **top,mid,bottom** etc.

Comment: This is awesome! Exactly what I was looking for and so clean and simple. Thanks! Note: one thing that I found odd was that the opacity works in all degrees except .8. Using that causes the background to go black. Everything below and above works fine.

Comment: One final issue now is getting an image to float in the window without taking on the opacity attribute. I've tried overlaying it in a separate DIV using the z-index object and that works, but the float applies to everything above the image and not just the text next to the image. How can I fix that?
Many Thanks!

Comment: @Mike can you show me the live code example of your issue.....that would be much better to understand the problem

Comment: I have made several changes, incorporating the ideas above, and have a relatively clean code. I like it.
However, in Internet Explorer I am getting page errors and the transparent backgrounds are not displaying.
Here is a link to an example page: w3.rkmpcservices.com/azdance/company.html

Furthermore, if you look at w3.rkmpcservices.com/azdance/artists.html, I am not only not getting the transparent background but the images are not displaying horizontally inline.

You can see the stylesheet code at w3.rkmpcservices.com/azdance/stylesheets/mainstyle.css

Thank you!!

Comment: Replace the w3 with www. When I used www this site would not allow me to post.

Comment: In Internet Explorer I am getting page errors and the transparent backgrounds are not displaying. And on the Artists page the pictures are not displaying horizontally inline.

Comment: Anybody have suggestions for my latest post (May 4th)?
Thanks!

Comment: Has everyone given up on me? Is there no fix for my problem? I changed my original coding to that recommended on this site, but now that it does not work nobody is offering a solution.